# Base64ing Unicode characters

Tags: unicode, base64

Can [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters be encoded and decoded with [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)?

I have attempted to encode the string 'الله', but when I decoded it all I got was '????'.

Comment: It would depend on how the Base64 routine is grabbing the data, what's the platform and the code? The answer is yes, they can, of course.

Comment: The data is being encoded in Delphi and decoded/used in PHP

Comment: Sorry, no clue about Delphi. But I provided an answer that proves that this problem has nothing to do with base64

Comment: Although it might be how are you decoding on PHP. Can't you provide an actual example with code? Unicode issues can be tricky, especially across languages/platforms

Comment: For the PHP side of things, I am using the built in base64_decode function.

Comment: If you just wanted unicode/(any other characters) in a URL format (possibly for CSS), you can use SVG: `list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><text>+</text></svg>")`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Base64 converts *binary* to text. If you want to convert text to a base64 format, you'll need to convert the text to binary using some appropriate encoding (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16) first.

Comment: @think123: Which bit? Not that I'm likely to know anyway, not knowing PHP, but splitting the task into bits is likely to help you find the answer through searching.

Comment: just converting text into binary using UTF-8, mainly.

Comment: @think123 I suspect a search for "PHP text utf-8" will give you a number of results then. If you don't get anywhere after reading them, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: I did find a solution - just `utf8_decode` the string after `base64_decode`ing a `base64_encode`d `utf8_encode`d string. Just for future reference.

Answer (score 17):

Of course they can. It depends on how your language or Base64 routine handles Unicode input. For example, Python's `b64` routines expect an encoded string (as Base64 encodes binary to text, not Unicode codepoints to text).

```
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Jul 31 2008, 22:53:39)
[GCC 4.1.2 (Ubuntu 4.1.2-0ubuntu4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 'ûñö'
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(a)
'w7vDscO2'
>>> base64.b64decode('w7vDscO2')
'\xc3\xbb\xc3\xb1\xc3\xb6'
>>> print '\xc3\xbb\xc3\xb1\xc3\xb6'
ûñö
>>>     
>>> u'üñô'
u'\xfc\xf1\xf4'
>>> base64.b64encode(u'\xfc\xf1\xf4')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/base64.py", line 53, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> base64.b64encode(u'\xfc\xf1\xf4'.encode('utf-8'))
'w7zDscO0'
>>> base64.b64decode('w7zDscO0')
'\xc3\xbc\xc3\xb1\xc3\xb4'
>>> print base64.b64decode('w7zDscO0')
üñô
>>> a = 'الله'
>>> a
'\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x84\xd9\x87'
>>> base64.b64encode(a)
'2KfZhNmE2Yc='
>>> b = base64.b64encode(a)
>>> print base64.b64decode(b)
الله
```

Comment: I'd just note that the returned string is not a unicode object.
it should be decoded as follows:

c = base64.b64decode(b).decode('utf-8')

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify which language(s) you're using, but try converting the string to a byte array (however that's done in your language of choice) and then base64 encoding that byte array.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET you can try this (encode):

```
byte[] encbuf;

encbuf = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(encbuf);
```

...and to decode:

```
byte[] decbuff;

decbuff = Convert.FromBase64String(this.ToString());
string decoded = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decbuff);
```